# RubberBand animation with React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add RubberBand animation for each hovered letter in my React project. I kinda got it going but when I hover one letter then the whole word gets animated instead of only that letter. I need only the letter that is hovered on would animate.
It working with css only but then when the cursor leaves the letter the animation gets cut off.

```
    function App() {
      const [hovered, setHovered] = React.useState(false);
      const toggleHover = () => setHovered(!hovered);

      return (
        <div className="text">
          <span
            className={hovered ? "rubberBand animated" : "rubberBand"}
            onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
            onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
          >
            a
          </span>

          <span
            className={hovered ? "rubberBand animated" : "rubberBand"}
            onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
            onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
          >
            b
          </span>
          <span
            className={hovered ? "rubberBand animated" : "rubberBand"}
            onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
            onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
          >
            c
          </span>
          <span
            className={hovered ? "rubberBand animated" : "rubberBand"}
            onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
            onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
          >
            d
          </span>
          <span
            className={hovered ? "rubberBand animated" : "rubberBand"}
            onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
            onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
          >
            e
          </span>
          <span
            className={hovered ? "rubberBand animated" : "rubberBand"}
            onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
            onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
          >
            f
          </span>
          <span
            className={hovered ? "rubberBand animated" : "rubberBand"}
            onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
            onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
          >
            g
          </span>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

```
   .text {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      font-weight: 700;
      font-size: 65px;
      color: #8a31c3;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
    }

    .rubberBand {
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-fill-mode: both;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      font-size: 90px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .rubberBand.animated {
      -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
      animation-name: rubberBand;
    }

    @keyframes rubberBand {
      from {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      }

      30% {
        transform: scale3d(1.25, 0.75, 1);
      }

      40% {
        transform: scale3d(0.75, 1.25, 1);
      }

      50% {
        transform: scale3d(1.15, 0.85, 1);
      }

      65% {
        transform: scale3d(0.95, 1.05, 1);
      }

      75% {
        transform: scale3d(1.05, 0.95, 1);
      }

      to {
        transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all your span tags share the same state, which causes all of them animate as a group. You can create a component `Letter`, where each component control its own state and also avoid code duplication:

```
const letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"];

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="text">
      // here I iterate over letters array to keep it dry
      {letters.map((letter, i) => (
        <Letter key={i}>{letter}</Letter>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

const Letter = ({ children }) => {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleHover = () => setHovered(!hovered);
  return (
    <span
      className={hovered ? "rubberBand animated" : "rubberBand"}
      onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
      onMouseLeave={toggleHover}
    >
      {children}
    </span>
  );
};
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked beautifully. I also removed onMouseLeave so the animation won’t   get cut off when the mouse leaves. Thanks!